# Stop long-running process in qthread

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, pyqt, qthread

I am trying to use `youtube-dl` module to download videos from youtube. I created a simple GUI to do a little job, I need when user clicks start button the thread will be called and download starts and sends data using `emit` method, when this data arrives to `read` function in `Main` class, the thread must stops after call `stop` function  from GUI, I tried to make event loop in qthread using `exec_()` and stop thread with `exit`, and I tried too use `terminate` but the GUI freezes.

The code that I used is:

```
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from youtube_dl import *

class Worker(QThread):
    data = pyqtSignal(object)
    def __init__(self):
        super(Worker, self).__init__()
        self.flag = True

    def sendHook(self, data, status = {'status':'downloading'}):
        self.data.emit(data)

    def stop(self):
        self.quit()
        self.exit()

    def run(self):
        self.y = YoutubeDL({'progress_hooks':[self.sendHook]})
        self.y.download(['https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LKIXbNW-B5g'])
        self.exec_()

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.l = QLabel("Hello")
        b = QPushButton("Start!")
        b.pressed.connect(self.connectthread)
        layout.addWidget(self.l)
        layout.addWidget(b)
        w = QWidget()
        w.setLayout(layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(w)
        self.show()

    def read(self, data):
        self.thread.stop()

    def connectthread(self):
        self.thread = Worker()
        self.thread.data.connect(self.read)
        self.thread.start()

app = QApplication([])
window = MainWindow()
app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By calling `self.exec_()` in the `run()` method of your worker you start a new event loop on this thread *after* the download finished, and this event loop then just keeps running. You don't need an event loop here, you only need a separate event loop if you want to move QObjects to it using their `moveToThread()` method to decouple them from the main event loop, but that is not needed here, you're not doing anything that requires a Qt event loop. That's also why calling `stop()` or `exit()` doesn't do anything, it only affects an event loop. The only way to stop this thread would be its `terminate()` method, and this also kind of works:

```
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from youtube_dl import *

class Worker(QThread):
    data = pyqtSignal(object)
    def __init__(self):
        super(Worker, self).__init__()
        self.flag = True

    def sendHook(self, data, status = {'status':'downloading'}):
        self.data.emit(data)

    def stop(self):
        self.terminate()
        print("QThread terminated")

    def run(self):
        self.y = YoutubeDL({'progress_hooks':[self.sendHook]})
        self.y.download(['https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LKIXbNW-B5g'])
        print("finished")

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.l = QLabel("Hello")
        b = QPushButton("Start!")
        b.pressed.connect(self.connectthread)
        layout.addWidget(self.l)
        layout.addWidget(b)
        w = QWidget()
        w.setLayout(layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(w)
        self.thread = None
        self.show()

    def read(self, data):
        print("read:", data)

    def connectthread(self):
        if self.thread is not None:
            # already running
            self.thread.stop()
            self.thread = None
            return
        self.thread = Worker()
        self.thread.data.connect(self.read)
        self.thread.start()

app = QApplication([])
window = MainWindow()
app.exec_()
```

Here I've altered your program so the first time the button is clicked the worker is started, the second time the thread is terminated and so on.

However terminating a thread this way is dangerous and discouraged. Python threads usually need to cooperate to be stoppable because by design they don't have a way to be interrupted. In this case it only works because PyQt is in control of the threads.

Unfortunately there isn't a way to gracefully stop a youtube-dl download, see [this related issue](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/issues/2764) for more information. In general there is no guarantee that killing the thread that called `download()` will actually stop the download. YoutubeDL supports a plugin system with different downloaders. To download a hls stream for example an external `ffmpeg` (or `avconv`) process is started, which would not be stopped by killing the worker thread. The same would be true for a downloader that uses other threads or processes internally, or for the post-processing steps that are also performed using `ffmpeg`.

If you want to be able to safely stop a download you'd have to use a separate process so you can use the `SIGINT` signal (same as pressing Ctrl-C) to tell it to stop.